# Can not swipe touchscreen in micromax bolt a064 model

Tags: touchscreen, micromax

i can't able to swipe [micromax bolt ao64](https://www.flipkart.com/micromax-bolt-a064-black-4-gb/p/itmeymgtezebmwtv) smartphone , means touch screen not work most of the time.... i bought this before 2 years....

I tried below things until now :

1)washed hands & cleaned touchscreen and tried

2)Restarted phone

3)Done **Factory reset** [ lost apps & other data ]

4)Removed all unwanted videos, images & freed up space.

I am using 3rd party charger from last 4 months , Is that caused issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using a 3rd party software is not a problem. It can be due to poor touch screen offered by Micromax which doesn't have long life. Or it can also be happened due to any accident with your phone. You can get a new Touch Screen from any Local shop or from the Micromax Service Center.

Comment: yes it was `touch screen ` problem after i used more than 2 + years......